How to get to useNuxtApp using the event.context for server side plugin Nuxt 3
I wrote a simple plugin that provides a resource that can be used on the client and server side of a Nuxt 3 app. Unfortunately calling useNuxtApp() fails on the server side in defineEventHandler. I saw this link https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/discussions/24251 which states that you cannot call useNuxtApp on the server side. How can I use the event.context to get to the plugin? When I console.log the event, I find that the context has no information relevant to my plugin.
Here is some code which illustrates the problem. My code in the module exposes the useNuxtApp because it is a Nuxt plugin
                  // Not Allowed here  
                   import {useNuxtApp} from '@nuxt/kit"
                  
                   defineEventHandler(event){
                     // Can I do this?
                     const kfactory = event.context.$kafkaFactory
                     // And use it like this
                     kfactory.publish(requestPayload)

                     //const requestPayload = event.readBody()
                    //Cannot find useNuxtApp 
                    // const { $kafkaFactory } = useNuxtApp()
                    // rest of code
                   }


The issue is that Nuxt complains the the import reference useNuxtApp is not allowed on the server side. However, if I try to reference useNuxtApp without the import I get a reference error that useNuxtApp() is not defined. That's why I provided the reference to the issue that had been raised regarding this issue. The code for the plugin has nothing to do with the error. The code works well, on the client side, it just does work when I used useNuxtApp on the server side as demonstrated in the code above

Would be very helpful if you provided the code of the nitro plugin as well

Added the relevant code causing issues

You should be able to add it to the event context in a Nitro plugin.

export default defineNitroPlugin((nitroApp) => {
  nitroApp.hooks.hook('request', (event) => {
    event.context.kafkaFactory = ...
  });
});


To ensure that it stays type-safe, you can create an index.d.ts file with the following code:
declare module 'h3' {
  interface H3EventContext {
    kafkaFactory?: <your-type-here>
  }
}

// important to export something
export {}


I am so grateful to you, you made my day. Thank you very much!

One issue with this solution is that it is called at every request which is problematic. Is it possible to have the kafkaFactory registered  only once so that adding to the context only occurs once?

The context is an attribute on the current request event. So if you need to use it in an event handler, you need to add it for every event (=request)
What exactly are you using this for and where is it used? Do you need it in event handlers?

Yes, I need to be able to use in an event Handler.  There is an event handler which sends a Kafka Payload to Kafka Queue. The goal is to make it possible to allow this module to configure and provide a Kafka instance so it can be used in an event handler

Is the request hook called every time there is a request sent to the event handler? I have modified the code to show what I want to do.

Yes, it is called on every request and it needs to be to modify event context of the current request.

Thank you. I was able to take a different approach, by working with server/plugins and dynamic imports

I was able to solve this by using plugins in ./server/plugins and also by incorporating auto imports
